# Python with emacs and windows XP

Tags: python, emacs, windows-xp, emacsw32

I am trying to set up Python under emacs on my company's computer
which runs windows XP (64bits).

I tried both python.el and python-mode.el without success.

My current problem is that whenever I use something like <kbd>C-c
C-c</kbd> to send a `.py`buffer to the python process, I get the
following error message

```
apply: Searching for program: no such file or directory, python
```

A `*Python*` buffer is created but it as no prompt and I don't know
how to interact with it.
Pressing <kbd>RET</kbd> inside the said buffer raises the following
error message

```
comint-send-string: Output file descriptor of Python is closed
```

which I fail to interpret.

Python seems to be correctly installed (and added to search path)
because <kbd>M-x shell RET python -i RET</kbd> correctly begins a Python shell
with the `>>>` prompt.

Do you have any idea about what is wrong with my setup?

Comment: windows + emacs never work fine.

Comment: I know that. I am trying to sneak an ubuntu distro on a spare computer.

Comment: Save yourself a lot of headache and pain: download virtualbox and install a minimal linux distribution; install some ssh client on the Windows machine and be on your merry way.

Comment: I actually found that there was a stray dash trailing after my path.
Strangely it did not broke usage from shell but prevented use from within emacs.
I guess the question is actually too localised. I voted for close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the value of a variable `python-command` ?

You can debug `run-python` function which is defined in python.el. This function creates the internal python process.

Just put a cursor inside the function and execute `M-x edebug-defun`. You can read more about debugging in the [doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Edebug.html#Edebug).

Comment: I left it default so it's `python`.
I'll check the debug.

Comment: I must admit I am a bit confused about what I should do for debugging the function. I did what you said but I just get a message: `run-python`.

Comment: OK, now you close the internal python buffer '*Python*' if any and send a region with C-c C-c. You should stop in the run-python. Then follow with emacs debug commands.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but I don't see what you mean by `stop in the run-python`

Comment: Sorry, I mean if you debug a function run-python and you send a region to python then this function will be called and you will be stopped in the debugger.

Comment: The debugger stops almost at the beginning of the function but I cannot guess what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

as for python-mode.el that kind of stuff should run

Please file a report at

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode